# Fluid/Liquid Layout - Multiple columns with padding/margins on either side

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive layout with a number of columns, spaced-out evenly with a 16px padding/margin on either side of them.

If I have 3 columns, naturally the width of each column would be set to 33%, however, with the 16px gap in-between each column, this makes up over 100%.

Using CSS, JavaScript or PHP...how would I be able to achieve this?

```
body {
    font: 0.75em Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    background: #CCC;
}
p {margin-bottom: 12px;}
h1 {
    font: 1.25em Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: teal;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#wrapper {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 32px;
}

.one-third {???}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jed8D/

Thank you.

Comment: My tip for you is to use a CSS preprocessor like LESS (http://lesscss.org) or SASS (http://sass-lang.com). You can easily assign the values to variables and therefore calculate the widths automatically.

Comment: why not using margin:x%?

Comment: @Akam - I'm needing a 16px gap specifically in-between each column...using a percentage for the distance would have variable results on the gap when resizing the browser.  Sven - I'll take a look into this, looks great...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be easily done through calc function in css3. Try this:

```
.one-third {
    width: calc((100% - 32px) / 3); //Where 100% is the width of container - 32px is the margin between two columns (16px + 16px) - 3 is the number of columns
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.one-third:nth-child(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

You can use calc() to calculate the size in pixels or percentage in css. and nth-child will help remove margin from every third column (presuming that you might have more multiple 3 column rows).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ab9Q/ Try and modify the width of the results tab in fiddle to see the effect. I think this is what you want.

Comment: beautiful solution @Jehanzeb.Malik!

Comment: @ user1752759 : Same solution I have given before the above user using jquery which is completely compatible in all the browsers, whereas CSS3 is not But  you have voted it down & you find this answer beautiful ? Is this fair ?

Comment: @Aratidgr8 Although your solution is cross-browser compatible it does not actively does what the OP was asking for. If you see in my fiddle you will notice a difference that when the browser is resized the columns re-calculate the width according to the width of there wrapper, whose width is relative to window width. If you bind "window" to resize and in callback do the calculation that you are doing in the document.ready it would be a better solution than mine.

Comment: @ jehanzeb-malik: Thanks...!!! for your valuable addition to make code responsive with window size. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your `css`

```
.one-third {
    float: left;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 29%;
}
```

but you need to create an element inside the `wrapper` after all `one-third div`

is that `<div class="clrboth"></div>`

and `css` for `clrboth` is

`.clrboth{clear:both;}`

Working example is http://jsfiddle.net/Jed8D/2/
[Note: Width can be differ in fiddle because it has low width, check it on a single page will work as you want.]

Comment: Try to avoid using border and padding in IE (especially in IE7). These have known issues and should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

Below code will do the needful, as it calculates the column width on the page load. No hard coded values.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var wrapperW = $("#wrapper").width();

    /* (Wrapper width - gap * nos.of columns) divided by nos.of columns     */
    var availableW = Math.floor((wrapperW - 16 * 3) / 3);       

    $(".one-third").width(availableW);

});

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 0.75em Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    background: #CCC;
}

p {margin-bottom: 12px;}

h1 {
    font: 1.25em Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: teal;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#wrapper {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 32px;
}

.one-third { margin:8px; float:left; }  /* Important change */

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="one-third"> 
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Column One Title</h1>
    </header>
<p>Phasellus commodo velit risus. Vivamus nunc lectus, molestie vel interdum ut, gravida congue lorem. Sed elementum lorem et dolor gravida in imperdiet quam lacinia. Aenean iaculis, elit vitae iaculis malesuada, nulla risus lobortis nulla, ut lacinia risus enim ut arcu. Duis ac ligula enim, eget consequat odio. Nunc condimentum arcu et erat dignissim at consequat lorem tincidunt. In quis consectetur orci. Quisque elit lectus, feugiat vitae sollicitudin in, lacini a ac velit.</p>
<p>Nam laoreet purus at turpis sollicitudin ut tincidunt nulla dapibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin egestas tristique nunc et suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras nec lacus arcu. Cras ligula quam, facilisis sit amet tristique non, ullamcorper ut dolor.</p>
<p>Donec posuere mi at urna congue non rutrum leo hendrerit. Nulla tempor vehicula eros, vitae ornare sem ornare eu. Etiam ultricies tristique malesuada. Maecenas pellentesque sem eu metus vulputate molestie. Nullam fringilla mauris eget metus imperdiet vulputate. Vivamus vulputate pretium tortor et commodo. Sed in volutpat lectus. Nam tincidunt blandit nunc, nec tincidunt mauris tempor ut. Nulla eu mattis nisl. Quisque pretium convallis venenatis. Praesent varius orci nec justo posuere porttitor sollicitudin ligula imperdiet. Cras fermentum mauris dolor. Proin at nunc turpis.</p>
<p>Morbi elit lorem, consectetur sed ullamcorper nec, viverra eu eros. Aenean molestie pellentesque ante facilisis pretium. Donec id mauris urna, at ornare lacus. Phasellus vel mattis magna. Phasellus at nisl ut metus ornare interdum a ac justo. Etiam suscipit lobortis tellus, vel lacinia neque placerat sed. In dictum, dui eget varius laoreet, ante ante semper orci, vel pulvinar mi velit eget lectus. Etiam ut odio ut dui consequat ullamcorper. Vestibulum sollicitudin scelerisque accumsan.</p>   
</div>  

<div class="one-third"> 
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Column Two Title</h1>
    </header>
<p>Phasellus commodo velit risus. Vivamus nunc lectus, molestie vel interdum ut, gravida congue lorem. Sed elementum lorem et dolor gravida in imperdiet quam lacinia. Aenean iaculis, elit vitae iaculis malesuada, nulla risus lobortis nulla, ut lacinia risus enim ut arcu. Duis ac ligula enim, eget consequat odio. Nunc condimentum arcu et erat dignissim at consequat lorem tincidunt. In quis consectetur orci. Quisque elit lectus, feugiat vitae sollicitudin in, lacini a ac velit.</p>
<p>Nam laoreet purus at turpis sollicitudin ut tincidunt nulla dapibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin egestas tristique nunc et suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras nec lacus arcu. Cras ligula quam, facilisis sit amet tristique non, ullamcorper ut dolor.</p>
<p>Donec posuere mi at urna congue non rutrum leo hendrerit. Nulla tempor vehicula eros, vitae ornare sem ornare eu. Etiam ultricies tristique malesuada. Maecenas pellentesque sem eu metus vulputate molestie. Nullam fringilla mauris eget metus imperdiet vulputate. Vivamus vulputate pretium tortor et commodo. Sed in volutpat lectus. Nam tincidunt blandit nunc, nec tincidunt mauris tempor ut. Nulla eu mattis nisl. Quisque pretium convallis venenatis. Praesent varius orci nec justo posuere porttitor sollicitudin ligula imperdiet. Cras fermentum mauris dolor. Proin at nunc turpis.</p>
<p>Morbi elit lorem, consectetur sed ullamcorper nec, viverra eu eros. Aenean molestie pellentesque ante facilisis pretium. Donec id mauris urna, at ornare lacus. Phasellus vel mattis magna. Phasellus at nisl ut metus ornare interdum a ac justo. Etiam suscipit lobortis tellus, vel lacinia neque placerat sed. In dictum, dui eget varius laoreet, ante ante semper orci, vel pulvinar mi velit eget lectus. Etiam ut odio ut dui consequat ullamcorper. Vestibulum sollicitudin scelerisque accumsan.</p>
</div>  

<div class="one-third"> 
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Column Three Title</h1>
    </header>
<p>Phasellus commodo velit risus. Vivamus nunc lectus, molestie vel interdum ut, gravida congue lorem. Sed elementum lorem et dolor gravida in imperdiet quam lacinia. Aenean iaculis, elit vitae iaculis malesuada, nulla risus lobortis nulla, ut lacinia risus enim ut arcu. Duis ac ligula enim, eget consequat odio. Nunc condimentum arcu et erat dignissim at consequat lorem tincidunt. In quis consectetur orci. Quisque elit lectus, feugiat vitae sollicitudin in, lacini a ac velit.</p>
<p>Nam laoreet purus at turpis sollicitudin ut tincidunt nulla dapibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin egestas tristique nunc et suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras nec lacus arcu. Cras ligula quam, facilisis sit amet tristique non, ullamcorper ut dolor.</p>
<p>Donec posuere mi at urna congue non rutrum leo hendrerit. Nulla tempor vehicula eros, vitae ornare sem ornare eu. Etiam ultricies tristique malesuada. Maecenas pellentesque sem eu metus vulputate molestie. Nullam fringilla mauris eget metus imperdiet vulputate. Vivamus vulputate pretium tortor et commodo. Sed in volutpat lectus. Nam tincidunt blandit nunc, nec tincidunt mauris tempor ut. Nulla eu mattis nisl. Quisque pretium convallis venenatis. Praesent varius orci nec justo posuere porttitor sollicitudin ligula imperdiet. Cras fermentum mauris dolor. Proin at nunc turpis.</p>
<p>Morbi elit lorem, consectetur sed ullamcorper nec, viverra eu eros. Aenean molestie pellentesque ante facilisis pretium. Donec id mauris urna, at ornare lacus. Phasellus vel mattis magna. Phasellus at nisl ut metus ornare interdum a ac justo. Etiam suscipit lobortis tellus, vel lacinia neque placerat sed. In dictum, dui eget varius laoreet, ante ante semper orci, vel pulvinar mi velit eget lectus. Etiam ut odio ut dui consequat ullamcorper. Vestibulum sollicitudin scelerisque accumsan.</p>
</div>  

<br style="clear:both;" /> <!-- Important Addition -->

</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/szFS8/ Does this look right?  If so, there is no fluid columns anymore.

Comment: This is definitely a fluid layout because it calculates the width of .one-third div based on the width of #wrapper which is mentioned in percentage in CSS.